# DNX beta8 keeps reinstalling when opening solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to update from ASP.NET 5 beta8 to RC1.

I have no references to beta8 whatsoever in my projects, but when opening my solution, I see the following happening in the DNVM console in Visual Studio:

> Installing to C:\Users\me.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8
>   Adding C:\Users\me.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin to
>   process PATH Installing to
>   C:\Users\me.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8 Adding
>   C:\Users\me.dnx\runtimes\dnx-coreclr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin to
>   process PATH Compiling native images for
>   dnx-coreclr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8 to improve startup performance...

I close Visual Studio, uninstall all beta8 runtime version, delete the packages folder, but this still happens.

**global.json:**

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test", "." ],
  "sdk": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
      "runtime": "clr",
      "architecture": "x86"
  }
}
```

**project.json:**

```
{
  "title": "MyProject.Api",
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.6",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "5.0.2"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you install the RC1 tooling for Visual Studio using the installer on http://get.asp.net?

Comment: Is there anything in your gulpfile.js that references beta8?

Answer (score 1):

update the `sdk` section in your `global.json` like this sample:

```
{
    "projects": [
        "src",
        "test"
    ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1"
    }
}
```

and you'll target the `1.0.0-rc1-update1`

Comment: I am referencing the sdk correct, as you have specified.

Comment: Do you use the last `ASP.Net 5` tools for Visual Studio ? (`update1`)

Comment: can you share your `project.json` and `global.json` ?. And did you try to use `dnu restore` to recreate a `project.lock.json` ?

Comment: Why do you reference "." as project's source in your `global.json` ?

Comment: Check for a launch settings file in the Properties folder of the web app and check settings in web.config in the wwwroot folder

Answer (score 0):

That's by design. The tooling always installs the version of the runtime embedded in it. It doesn't affect your application though, you can still change the versions and do whatever you want.